# Should $HOME or /var/opt/ be used for files that a user does not directly access but are user specific?

Tags: linux, filesystems, home-directory

The linux file system standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard identifies /home/username/ as the location for a users files and settings.  It also identifies /var/opt/ as variable data for add-on packages.

It is clear to me that a database should store it's backend files in /var/opt/ and user documents should be stored in /home/user/

Which classification should system utilisation and monitoring data be stored?  Ignoring the permissions, visibility and user opinion concerns, should the data be in $HOME because is relates specifically to a user's activities or should it be placed in something like /var/opt/prog/user/ as they are not the user's files and the user is not expected to access them directly?

Comment: This may be considered a question of opinion. My personal inclination would be to put them into /var/opt/prog/user, just to be sure that the user won't monkey with them.

Comment: The rule of thumb I'd use that everything the user has under his control is in $HOME. If the user shouldn't be allowed to delete the files, or do with them whatever he wants, they don't belong in $HOME.